# Spring JPA Query by Example exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I try to get data with spring data an using example matcher for filter them
but when passing empty example object to Example class it does not working

```
       Example<MyEntity> example1 = Example.of(new MyEntity(), ExampleMatcher.matching());
```

this is part of sql generated for get data from database

```
where
     ?=1
```

binding parameter [1] as [BIT] - [true]

and this error occur
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
Fail to convert to internal representation

Comment: What are you expecting? For me passing an empty example is just wrong usage.

Comment: i expect if i dont set any property to example object spring return all data and not generate any where clause condition

Comment: If you want all, why don't you `CrudRepository#findAll` instead?

Comment: Client requests may have empty filters, in which case all data should be returned.
I actually want to use exampleMatcher to filter my data, and these filters are entered from the client.